# How to Record video in xamarin.forms cross-platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to record video in android,windows and ios.
Reference Link:- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/ContentPage/CustomRenderer

Getting following error:
[image]

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in mscorlib.ni.dll

WinRT information:The current capture source does not have an independent photo stream

Comment: It's advisable to post all code and error messages here, rather than linking to stuff... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the bit about photo capture (since you're doing video capture) and see if that helps.

```
//PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aea71a1b-20ea-4dd2-ae24-d082929e1301/cannot-find-front-back-camera-in-windows-81-store-app?forum=winappswithcsharp)